# Is it possible to pass a color ramp to a node group?

Tags: materials, node-editor, color

Are there any addons or other features in Blender that allow a Blender user to write nodes that pass in color ramps and reuse them in a group node? If the answer is yes, then what are the steps?

Single colors and vectors can be passed into a group node (reusable function).  MixRGB node can simulate simple color ramp for two colors. So these items can be excluded from potential answers.

[image]

In response to a question below, a crude and compromised set of nodes.  Candidate for enhancement and promotion to group.

Comment: Could help: [Build ColorRamp out of math nodes](https://blender.stackexchange.com/q/40120/78972) and [Control a ColorRamp from outside of a Nodegroup](https://blender.stackexchange.com/q/170114/78972)

Comment: Could you say what you want to do with the color ramp?

Comment: Why the insistence on an opening question mark? There is no such thing in the English language

Comment: @scurest ⚙⛓

Comment: And that rimes with?

Answer (score 2):

A *Color Ramp Node* is a combination of Sliders (each slider is a color and a position). The problem is that the number of sliders in a color ramp is not fixed. I can contain just one slider or several. So blender can not make color ramp input since it differs a lot.

So the only way is to use value and color inputs.